# Picking an element from XML node using a given text

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Book>
    <Name>Title1</Name>
    <Name>Title2</Name>
    <Name>Title3</Name>
  </Book>
</Root>
```

I would like to select a specific element from Book node and store it in a variable (so that I can access the InnerText of that element at later point in PowerShell script). I tried following approach but it returns all elements. What would be the right way to select the child element using given text (ex. Title1).

```
$item = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Book/[Name='Title1'])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to select the book node or the name node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a `Name` node based on the inner text, use the `.` self-reference for the attribute name in the xpath clause:

```
$item = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Book/Name[. = 'Title1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select the `Name` node, then @Mathias R. Jessen's answer will work - but if you're trying to find the parent node with that name, your XPath needs to be adjusted like so:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//Book[Name='Title1']");
```

For example:

```
$xml = [xml]'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Book>
    <Name>Title1</Name>
    <Name>Title2</Name>
    <Name>Title3</Name>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name>Title4</Name>
    <Name>Title5</Name>
  </Book>
</Root>'

$xml.SelectSingleNode("//Book[Name='Title5']");
```

results in:

```
Name            
----            
{Title4, Title5}
```

Be aware that this will get you the **first** `Book` node that matches, even if multiple match.